# How can i know which php page request current php script?

Tags: php, httpwebrequest

I'm beginner in php and want to know if I have page A.php ,B.php and C.php and page A.php send request to page C.php how can i know that the request come from A.php not any other page.
Thanks

Comment: How is it sending the request to page C?  Header redirect?  Include?  HTML Link?  META refresh tag?

Comment: Doesn't referer only give you domain? You could pass an identifier variable..!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) value.

Comment: While you're at it, do `var_dump($_SERVER)` and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check out php's [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable. It sounds like you want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER]`.

**Note:** This is not going to be 100% accurate as it uses the information from the browsers user agent, which can be spoofed and some don't send that information at all.

There is no 100% guaranteed way of having this information, though that would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a variable to the GET array of the URL call and check that - 
www.yoururl.com/pageC?callingPage=a
Something like that.
The referrer variable isnt necissarily reliable :/
Also, since you need to know what page you're coming from, wouldn't you also be therefore doing something with that page's data? If that's the case, you could pass the identification variable with the data being sent anyways. If not, then you could still use the method I just mentioned.

Comment: That isn't necessarily always going to work either... Unfortunately, there is no 100% way to have this information.

Comment: @JustinWood I fail to see how passing a variable in the get string wouldn't work absolutely 100% of the time? He didn't give us design restrictions and that's a perfectly valid way to do it, and as far as I'm concerned it WOULD indeed be reliable way to do it. Please let me know if you have a case where that wouldn't work (extraneous server configs aside)

Comment: Same reason you can't rely on `$_SERVER`. All modern browsers to my knowledge will send that information along. If you rely on a get/post string, that information can still be intercepted somewhere between and removed or modified (which is quite easy to do). I'm not saying your approach is a poor one, I'm just saying that it isn't 100% correct all the time.

Comment: Sure but in that case you're talking about security and hoping that somebody doesn't want to tamper with your request, which is essentially like saying that using an HTML form element is not a reliable way to transmit data. If you're talking about architecture, I don't see why this isn't reliable. :/
That said, what about ze $_SESSION variable, in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, within C.php:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://www.somesite.com/A.php'){
  // Do it
} else {
  // Do not
}
```

To improve reliability, it's possible to use other data (eg. session variables) passed (and more so if you're using forms). If its just a straight link with nothing else, its more difficult.